# Recover "passwd" file in fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, passwd, etcpasswd

I was trying something and execute the below command

```
sudo mv /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.bak
```

Now I am getting the below error whenever I am trying to run `sudo`

```
sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database
```

I am not an expert in Linux stuff. Anyone has any idea how can I recover it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot a live Linux that will give you ability to act as root. (Alternatively [pass `init=/bin/bash` in your current bootloader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34462/108618) to boot your current Linux to an elevated shell.)
2. Mount the filesystem holding the troublesome file. Example:

   ```
   mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
   ```

   You need to know which device to mount; helpful commands: `lsblk`, `fdisk -l`. This step will be more complex if you're using LVM, encryption and/or such.
3. Rename the file back. Example:

   ```
   mv /mnt/etc/passwd.bak /mnt/etc/passwd
   ```
4. Unmount the filesystem, this should sync the change. Example:

   ```
   umount /mnt
   ```
5. Reboot; boot the fixed OS normally.

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't the OP append `1` to the boot command (in `grub`?) so that it boots to single user run level ... and then `mv` the `passwd` file back?